# tkinter image appearing partially white instead of correct colour

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

Recently i have been trying to get gifs to work with tkinter and after some research i figured out how i was going to do it and wrote a class to make playing them easier

```
class GifWrapper():
    def __init__(self, parent, file=None):
        self.file=file
        self.parent=parent
        if file:
            self.info=parse(file=file)
        else:
            raise GifError("expected file to be passed")
        print(str(self.info.frames)+" "+str(len(self.info.delays)))
        self.frames=[]
        for i in range(0, self.info.frames):
            self.frames.append(PhotoImage(file=self.file, format="gif -index {}".format(i)))
            print("added frame {}".format(i))
    async def play(self):
        curFrame=0
        for i in self.info.delays:
            await asyncio.sleep(i/100)
            self.parent["image"]=self.frames[curFrame]
            curFrame+=1
```

However when i tested this out i noticed that my gif was pretty strange as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FsZa.jpg), the first frame seems to be only slightly affected, the second frame seems perfectly ok and the rest are pretty badly affected by the issue, i remember reading somewhere that pixels with an alpha of 0 were treated as transparent in PhotoImage files so i assume that this might be the problem however i think it's weird that the first and second images are affected differently, is there a way to change this?